# How to move array elements down from a certain piont?

Tags: java

I have a array of variables, and I want to delete 1 of the elements and then shift the whole array down to fill that spot that was removed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and before you ask, no this is not homework.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you fixed on using arrays instead of a more flexible data structure like a Collection?

Comment: Post some code, so that we can understand your question better.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, use an `ArrayList` (or some other list implementation) instead, where this is already implemented for you. (The exact implementation you'd want to use will depend on how often you need to perform removals vs how often you need to retrieve or set by index, etc. With more context we could help you more.)

Otherwise, use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, array, index, array.length - index - 1);
// Assuming it's a reference type array: null out the last element so it
// doesn't prevent garbage collection
array[array.length - 1] = null;
```

Comment: `ArrayList` will still not be a good option - it will still need to shift all the elements

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I've edited - it depends on how often you need to do this vs other operations. There are *lots* of variables involved, basically - I wouldn't just recommend LinkedList here, as that will then be awful if the OP needs to do a lot of get/set by index. (It can also be significantly less efficient in terms of memory.)

Comment: It is seldom that you should use a `LinkedList` over an `ArrayList`. See for example the following articles (a bit old, but probably still relevant): [article 1](http://onjava.com/onjava/2001/05/30/optimization.html) and [article 2](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue111.html). Probably due to the fact a `LinkedList` has to wrap each element to be able to create the link between the elements

Comment: @Robin: That second article is *very* poorly written - it ignores the exact case where LinkedList shines: when you remove from a linked list *having already iterated as far as you need to*. The author mentions the idea, but says he hasn't tested it... and then claims that it's "probably never" going to be faster than his own collection or ArrayBlockingQueue. There are lots of usage patterns for collections that are simply ignored here.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in an array will not be efficient, especially if you need to provide the array's shrinking:

- if you do not need to shrink you can just swap all the elements till the end.
- if you need to shrink, then the only option will be to allocate new array and copy over all the elements.

A better option for this task will be `LinkedList`. It provides an operation for removing arbitrary element and it  does not require any shifting for fixing the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best solution would be to use an `ArrayList`

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //add Elements
        list.add("test1");
        list.add("test2");
        list.add("test3");

        //remove Element 2 (->1)
        list.remove(1);

        //print Element 2
        System.out.println(list.get(1));
        //output: test3
```

If you realy want to us an Array:

```
    private void removeElement(String[] array, int index) {
    final int arrayLength = array.length;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            array[i - 1] = array[i];

            if (i == arrayLength - 1) {
                array[i] = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use the `Arrays.asList` and `List#toArray` methods to convert the array temporarily to a `List`, use the available `remove` method of the `List`, and convert it back to an array.

```
Object[] arrayToShrink = ...;
List<Object> shrinkedList = new ArrayList<Object>( Arrays.asList( arrayToShrink ) );
shrinkedList.remove( objectToRemove );
Object[] shrinkedArray = shrinkedList.toArray( new Object[shrinkedList.size()] );
```

Short code wise, but most likely not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Did you try this? Arrays.asList().remove(...) will throw.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good catch. No I did not try this, but I will correct the answer. Seems I need an extra line of code